# Transimpedance amplifier: weird simulation results

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, stability, transimpedance-amplifier, tina

I am working on a photodiode transimpedance amplifier based on an [OPA2374](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2374.pdf) and decided to simulate it in TINA TI.

However, several unexpected issues arose.

1. AOL and GBW product vary significantly with input common-mode voltage and supply voltage
2. Degraded stability when photodiode generates a DC current

Here I do a sweep of the input DC offset (so as to not saturate at the negative power supply) and plot the open loop gain of the op-amp.

This is the schematic I used:
[image]

And these are the results:
[image]

Similar results are obtained when sweeping the negative voltage supply:
[image]

I must stress that all the ranges I swept through are well within the input common-mode range and supply voltage ranges for the OPA2374.

Also, as a further sanity check, I redid the circuit with all the test fixtures and the same op-amp macromodel in LTspice. The results and behavior were identical.

However, when changing just the op-amp to one already present in the LTspice device library, I could not observe any variation when doing sweeps of either DC offset or supply voltage.

What's happening here? Is this a case of a misbehaving op-amp model or something else?

Comment: Have you compared with the data sheet?

Comment: Yes. They don't match. See here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2374.pdf?ts=1707713096781&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FOPA2374%252Fpart-details%252FOPA2374AID%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Docb-tistore-promo-asc_opn_en-cpc-storeic-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DDevice%2526ds_k%253DOPA2374AID%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gad_source%253D1%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMI-c7x_v6khAMV1a2DBx0rJgdxEAAYASAAEgJykvD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds

Comment: I also found this issue being raised for a different TI op amp model: https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/1120326/opa855-q1-the-relation-between-open-loop-gain-simulation-results-and-reference-voltage-of-operational-amplifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the datasheet, but I wouldn't be surprised if the loop gain changes due a different common-mode input voltage. They will define how hard you drive the differential input stage (the overdrive voltage) and this can change the small signal parameters of your input stage, such as the transconductance.

As far as I know there exists a "Boyle" macromodel for op-amps which typically includes an actual transistor input-stage, so changes in common-mode voltage can be reflected on the simulations.

The input stage is a great contributor to all the open-loop voltage gain, as such, it also dominates the noise performance of the op-amp.

The question is, does this variation in the low-frequency open-loop gain be tolerated by your design? Does a 20dB decrease of gain at those low frequencies important to you?

EDIT:
On a second thought, perhaps 20dB might be a bit too much of a variation for an op-amp. Maybe there's something not properly model. However, I think you should be able to account for this in your design.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. 20dB difference is a lot.

Comment: And I also found this issue being raised before here: https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/1120326/opa855-q1-the-relation-between-open-loop-gain-simulation-results-and-reference-voltage-of-operational-amplifier

Comment: I think this difference might affect the stability, the feedback capacitor is dimensioned for a certain GBW product.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs but use it in your actual design. Does it make a difference in your final design? If you can frequency compensate it, you can make it good enough to make it stable in both situations. Is the distortion coming out of the amplifier good enough for you in both situations?

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs you should also consider whether that common-mode variation is expected in your system. Where's that voltage coming from?

Comment: The voltage would be provided either by some batteries in the range of 3 to 4.5V or from a lab power supply. The common mode input voltage is provided by a simple voltage divider, that I excluded for quicker prototyping.

Comment: Also with regards to the output distortion, both V+ = 200mV and V+ = Vs/2 give the same transient response. This might be a fluke though, because the gain of the TIA is 80dB and the minimum AOL of the OPA2374 is also 80dB

Comment: Also another thing crossing my mind is that perhaps the fact that the op-amp is rail-to-rail input might mean that when changing from small to big offset voltage the input pair changes and the resulting gain of PMOS and NMOS stages would differ

Comment: I don't know what frequency you're using, but it seems like that at high frequencies the loop gain difference isn't much. The low-frequency difference should govern the gain error. A quick calculation shows that this should give 0.01% and 0.001%. Is that considerable for you?

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs RR is a good point. There can be jumps in the Gm of the input stage, though well-design RR OpAmps should minimize this variation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151476/discussion-between-virgil-tibbs-and-designalog).